# Proving that $\mathbb{N}_{\text{even}}$ is not definable in $\langle \mathbb{N},<\rangle$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm looking for a simple proof (or a reference) for the following claim:

The set of even natural numbers is not definable in the structure $\langle \mathbb{N},<\rangle$.

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214869/2-mathbb-z-is-not-a-definable-set-in-the-structure-mathbb-z-0-s